# What is the best practice for python connecting to postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm working on a python script that will need to connect to a postgreSQL server. What the best practice for the username and password? In this tutorial ZetCode is just using the username and password (if needed) in the code itself. Is this the right way or should there be some sort of hashed file to read from?

http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqlpythontutorial/

Comment: For starters, I would store them in a configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the username and password in a file, then restricting access to that file would be a good start.

Storing a hashed username or password won't work, because you cannot undo a hash function.

If you think that storing the username and password in plain text isn't secure enough in your situation, encrypt them.  When the script starts, it asks for the passphrase. That passphrase is then hashed using [PBKDF2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbkdf2) or [scrypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrypt/). Use that hash as the key for encryption/decryption. See [cryptographic right answers](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html).

This does mean that your script needs operator input every time it starts!